What is a standard mathematical model for the likelihood that past results predict future performance?
I’m new to statistics. I would like to understand some logical, mathematical, and philosophical foundations and justifications for building up a simple applied theory of “likelihood”, and am less interested in complex and heuristic techniques more commonly used in practice.
I was thinking of defining some scenario in logic, first (or type theory).
The scenario is a function that has inputs and outputs and there is a measurement of error from the correct intended output.
The question is about justifying how likely something is, based on past performance.
I think the bulk of the analysis is regarding the mathematical characteristics of the input space.
If the set of possible inputs is infinite, we might ask if there is no amount of sampling with the function that would justify the test data as an accurate predictor.
I think a key aspect is that the input set is something akin to “continuous”, topologically connected, or something. This might allow us to prove that a given sampling tells us more about the space than just the points we sampled, for example if we know the value at intermediary points cannot vary beyond a certain degree.
Is there a basic formula where we can define probability as the expected accuracy of the output of a function repeated N times, which is the same as the values already obtained, since we assume the function is “constant” in its behavior, so long as we choose a valid “sampling space”? (And I guess the function being deterministic or not is also important.)
A long, tutorial-like answer is appreciated. I’m also open to edits to make my question more canonical in statistical terms. Thanks.

I'm not clear on what is being asked here.  So you're thinking of some function in which you control the inputs?  The output is known a priori, but for some reason the outputs contain some sort of error, and your question is to determine what output is "likely" conditioned on the outputs you have observed so far from this function under the controls you specified?

@DemetriPananos I get the feeling that this is kind of like, "Under what circumstances should we expect to predict the future?" Julius, is that correct, you want to know when you have a good handle on the future and when you don't?
